# Mongoose populate does not populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two collections into my MongoDB database: **users** and **components**.

The users' primary key is *_id* which is Number. It is referenced by the *created_by* and *updated_by* fields of a component document.

Everything works well except for the *populate* and I can't figure it out why. It leaves the value instead of the corresponding user document. I also tried to use ObjectIds instead of Numbers but nothing changed.

Any help will be appreciated.

I listed above the models and routing sources.

### Component and User models

#### models/user.js

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```

#### models/component.js

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const componentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    category: String,
    package: String,
    box: Number,
    cell: Number,
    quantity: Number,
    note: String,
    link: String,
    created_by: {
        type: Number,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    created_on: Date,
    updated_by: {
        type: Number,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    updated_on: Date
});

const Component = mongoose.model('Component', componentSchema);

export default Component;
```

#### models/index.js

```js
import Component from './component';
import User from './user';

const models = { Component, User };

export default models;
```

### Middleware

```js
import models from './models';

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.context = { models };
    next();
});
```

### Components routing

```js
import { Router } from "express";
const router = Router();
...
var getComponents = async (req, res) => {
    const query = req.context.models.Component.find().populate('users');

    try {
        const results = await query;
        return res.status(200).send({ results: results });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: err });
    }
}
...
router.get('/', getComponents)

export default router;
```

I also tried to use the *exec*

```js
var getComponents = (req, res) =>
    req.context.models.Component.find().populate('users').exec().then(components => res.status(200).send({ results: components })).catch(err => res.status(400).send({ error: err }));
```

but I got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use an existing field name in populate path like  .populate('created_by')

Here is the test:

I first created a user with this request body:

```
{
    "_id": 111,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastname": "River",
    "email": "abc@def.net",
    "password": "123123"
}
```

Then I created two components:

```
{
    "name": "component 1",
    "quantity": 1,
    "created_by": 111
}
```

And

```
{
    "name": "component 2",
    "quantity": 2,
    "created_by": 111
}
```

And using this code:

```
const result = await Component.find().populate("created_by");
```

The result is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5de7a89e9039c738b4008d41",
        "name": "component 1",
        "quantity": 1,
        //other fields
        "created_by": {
            "_id": 111,
            "firstName": "John",
            "email": "abc@def.net",
            "password": "123123",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5de7a8aa9039c738b4008d42",
        "name": "component 2",
        "quantity": 2,
        //other fields
        "created_by": {
            "_id": 111,
            "firstName": "John",
            "email": "abc@def.net",
            "password": "123123",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: I tried but nothing changed. I wrote it on the post

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli ok I will try this myself in a sample application, and will inform you.

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli but before can you try to populate like this? populate('created_by');

Comment: Yes it works, it is the name of the field not of the collection

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli yes in the populate path you need to use field name. 
Can you please accept my answer if it worked.

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli I was first to answer with correct answer, why did you mark another answer, this is not fair.

Comment: Sorry, the answers were identical so I miss-clicked. I solved it.

Comment: Is there a way to use the _id as Number with the populate?

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli it may be possible if you use Number type in both sides, but I already see in your question both types are Number, so maybe just populate change may work, can you revert the schema change, and try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203591/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-angelo-pettinelli).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be:

```
created_by: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
```

Then, query like this,

```
Component.find().populate('created_by');
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using the collection name instead of the field name.

Comment: How is this different from my answer? I think Angelo Pettinelli marked this as answer wrongly.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Here is the thing, if you check mongoose's official documentation the you would see they are using `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` not `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. In that sense, mine is more appropriate that yours IMO.

Answer (score 1):

you can do somthing like this.

```
created_by: { type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
```

And query

```
Component.find().populate('created_by');
```